# What is a conflicting transaction?

Tags: transaction, double-spending, white-paper, legacy-protocol

The term is used many times on the whitepaper but I can't find a definition. What would be examples of a conflicting transaction?

[Extract form Whitepaper](https://iota.org/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf#page=2&zoom=auto,-70,304):

> The main idea of the tangle is the following:  to issue a transaction, users must
>   work  to  approve  other  transactions.   Therefore,  users  who  issue  a  transaction  are
>   contributing  to  the  network’s  security.   It  is  assumed  that  the  nodes  check  if  the
>   approved  transactions  are  not  conflicting.   If  a  node  finds  that  a  transaction  is  in
>   conflict with the tangle history, the node will not approve the conflicting transaction
>   in either a direct or indirect manner³.

Comment: Please provide more context. A citation of an extract from the whitepaper, you don't understand due to the missing definition, would increase the quality of your Question a lot.

Comment: First appearance on final of page 2: "It is assumed that the nodes check if the approved transactions are not conflicting". Hence my question, what would that be?

Comment: make sure your questions fullfill the [qualitystandards](https://iota.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 2):

Transactions are conflicting if they try to spend the same money from the same address (and the address does not include enough money to satisfy both at the same time - but this should not happen anyway, as compliant clients will move the remaining balance to a change address - but can of course happen if an adversary tries this).

Either this can be because there is a real double spend (e. g. somebody tried to send the same funds to two different addresses) or in case somebody reattaches their transactions (only one of the transfers can confirm then).

Comment: Can't we disallow spending the same money from the same address, by using some distributed mutual exclusion schemes?

Comment: The answer was from before the Chrysalis update. With Chrysalis, UTXO and white-flagging are used to determine which one of the conflicting transactions wins, and so both can be confirmed. See https://iota.cafe/t/conflict-white-flag-mitigate-conflict-spamming-by-ignoring-conflicts/233

Comment: I have one basic question, why are conflicting transactions temporarily allowed in tangle and later dealt with, why not deal with them using some safeguard mechanisms that prevents conflicting transactions spending from the same address. I am new to this topic, so my question may seem puerile.

Comment: @DMitra The problem is the same as with any other distributed system: When a node receives a transaction it cannot now with certainty that another node has not yet received a conflicting transaction (which should take only seconds, but could take longer to get synchronized). And once a transaction is "in the tangle", you cannot easily remove it without affecting its descendants.